# Dynamically added buttons wont work from the first click

Tags: c#, asp.net

i know there is a lot of questions similar to mine but none of them solved my problem.

**The Idea:** 
i have two pages the first one is a login page and the other one is to show the logged in person attendance, in the attendance page i have two tabs one for the employee itself and the other one is to dynamically show the names of the employees under him, the second tab is presented as buttons that contain the employees name, and when you click it, it shows that person attendance.

**The Problem:**
when i click on the button it refresh the page without doing anything then when i click it again it works and calls the method i needed, so my question is why it doesn't work from the first click ?

**Solution Attempt:**
i created the buttons in code behind this way :

```
                   var button = new Button
                    {
                         ID = "Button " + a,
                     CommandArgument = myEmp[a].ToString(), //id of employee
                         Text = GetName(myEmp[a]), // name of employee
                        CausesValidation = false
                    };
                    button.Command += GetINAndOutManagers; //method on click
                var cell = new HtmlTableCell();
                var row = new HtmlTableRow();
                    cell.Controls.Add(button);
                    row.Cells.Add(cell);
       myTable.Rows.Add(row); // just for organization i put them in a table
```

and in my html page :

```html
<table id="myTable" runat="server" class="table table-bordered"></table>
```

as a place holder.

**1-** i have JavaScript and jquery in my page but even when i remove them it doesn't work.

**2-** i tried using html buttons instead in code behind put still don't work.

**3-** i tried putting it in page init and page preinit but no result.

the only time it worked when i put the buttons in the main page not the content page i don't know why, and i noticed when i click the button for the first time it doesn't consider it as a post back.

any ideas ?

**EDIT**

so to make it easier i deleted everything in my page load method 
and in my page init method i have this code only.

```
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = new Button();
        pnlInfo.Controls.Add(btn);
        btn.ID = "Button" + 1.ToString();
        btn.Text = "Test button" + 1.ToString();
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(btnSubmit_click);
    }
```

and the method on click is like this:

```
 private void btnSubmit_click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("**************in*****************");

}
```

so i only login and then it will redirect me to the second page which contains one button only created as you see in my page init method, no tabs no nothing

and in my html is this

```html
<asp:Panel ID="pnlInfo" runat="server">
</asp:Panel>
```

with some css and divs that's all, and it's still won't work from the first click !

Comment: "it works and calls the method i needed" - where is your method?

Comment: public void GetINAndOutManagers(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {
            empformngrID = e.CommandArgument.ToString(); } this is my method

Comment: does GetINAndOutManagers method hits (with breakpoint inside) when you click first time?

Comment: @aleha No it does not

Comment: https://forums.asp.net/t/1366451.aspx?Programatically+create+buttons+in+code+behind  you are missing click handler.

Comment: @aleha i actually did try this but the result is the same it fires up on the second click !

Comment: there is to few code provided to make any assumptions. Please paste full codebehind of your page and give a link to it.

Comment: @aleha i edit my question, hope this help ?

Comment: The button click event doesn't get subscribed to when you load the subordinate page. But the event does get attached & subscribed to page reload. You need to debug your code. Suggest you watch some videos on debugging

Comment: @Jeremy i did debug my page but apparently i was debugging the wrong one, where the problem was in my login page ! see my answer for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Oh Gosh, i found my solution

in my login page i used this code to transfer to my second page:

```
Server.Transfer("About.aspx", true);
```

so my buttons did not work, but when i change the code to this:

```
Response.Redirect("About.aspx");
```

everything worked !
well i'm an asp.net beginner so i don't know why that solved 
my problem. but thanks everyone, hope this help someone else too.